# Update State after `axios.post()`

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, axios, state

## Scenario

Using the Express framework to modify a MongoDB I am able to add documents to a collection named `faculties`. Also, the dropdownbox displaying the property `name` of the documents in collection `faculties`, when I can inspect it after the post method is completed. However, when I pass the state, and retrieve the `faculties` collection from it with: `const { faculties } = state;` and then inspect the properties `name` of the array of documents of collection `faculties`, It doesn't show the most recent addition to the database. (I am looking for the property 'id' of the newly inserted `faculty` document with name `exampleFaculty` to implement many-to-many relationships).

## Attempts

1. I tried applying a `forceUpdate()` to update the state, however from what I understood, this updates the `render` instead of the state. Nevertheless the render is updated but the state is not. This is the implementation:

```
this.forceUpdate();
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/putFaculty', {name: message});
this.forceUpdate();
ManyToManyDbMain.Main(message,collectionName,this.state) // implement many to many relationships in db
```

2. I tried `this.setState(this.state);` to update the state:

```
this.forceUpdate();
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/putFaculty', {name: message});
this.forceUpdate();
this.setState(this.state);
ManyToManyDbMain.Main(message,collectionName,this.state) // implement many to many relationships in db
```

3. I tried directly calling the fetch method to update the state:

```
this.forceUpdate();
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/putFaculty', {name: message});
this.forceUpdate();
this.getFaculties()
this.setState(this.state);

ManyToManyDbMain.Main(message,collectionName,this.state) // implement many to many relationships in db
```

Where the fetch method consists of:

```
// read the mongodb collection faculties in database "education"
    getFaculties= () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties')
                .then((data) => data.json())
                //set property "faculties" within the state" (won't throw error if you haven't defined property "faculties" within state".
                .then((res) => this.setState({ faculties: res.data })); 
    };
```

4. Using the response of the `axiom.post(..)` method to read the new faculties from that:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/putFaculty', {name: message})
                          .then(response => {
                            const {faculties} = this.state;
                            alert(response.data)
                            alert(response.name)
                            faculties.push(response.data);
                            this.setState({faculties});
                          })
```

But that returns an `object Object` and I do not yet know how to read the properties of that object, I tried mapping it into a `.name` property with: `response.map((dat) => dat.name)` but the response had no function named `map`.

5. Since the state gets automatically updated every second with:

```
this.getFaculties();
        if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
            let interval = setInterval(this.getFaculties, 1000);
            this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
        }
```

6. I tried adding a sleep method of 5 seconds with the false expectation that the state would automatically be updated before the state is passed to the `ManyToManyDbMain.Main()` method. Instead the website/code is frozen for 7 seconds, (meaning the state does not get updated either), before the code continues.

## Question

How can I update the state after the `axios.post()`, so that the latest document of collection `faculties` is included in the state that is passed to the `ManyToManyDbMain.Main(..)`?

#### Ignored shortcuts/XY-problem solutions:

The following solutions to the xy-problem are acknowledged but not persued.

1. I could manually generate all the id's for all documents, and just push them to the database, that way I have the Id's in the `App.js` when I need them. However, the reason to implement many-to-many relationships in the DB, is because it is designed to be a small database used (potentially) by many users, hence I want to reduce computation time (applying search queries to find subset id's) at the cost of a bigger database. That also means I don't want to create a separate system in the website that manages all the created Id's and prevents double Id's when MongoDb already has an optimised Id allocation system.
2. I could add a second loop every n-milliseconds that checks whether some boolean indicates whether a new faculty is added, and launch a "get Id method" from there. But I think that makes the code unnecessarily complex, difficult to test, potentially unreliable with multiple users, and computationally intensive, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `axios` .then() method to set the component's state.

for example -

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties')
  .then(res => {
    /** Console here to get an actual response from server */
    console.log(res);
    this.setState({
      faculties: res.data.results
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and quick response, your solution breaks `dat.facultyName={faculties.map((dat) => dat.name)}` with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` as it appears to be incompatible with my implementation of `fetch` as specified in attempt 3. Including `.then((data) => data.json())` and disabling your `catch` method, it breaks on `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.json is not a function`. With `catch` method enabled, it does not show anything in the state anymore, it becomes undefined. How could 
I pass the faculty name `exampleFaculty`  to your `axiom.get`?

Comment: axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties/${faculty_name})

Comment: According to your comment, your fetched data is not properly formatted (not an array of objects). You need to check the server response. That's why I put a comment in the code /** Console here to get an actual response from server */

Comment: I assume you meant `axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getFaculties$faculty_name')` With a variable defined `var faculty_name = "exampleFaculty";` before the `axios.get(..)` is called.

Comment: You can use a string literal here. like `${serverURL}users/${userData.id}` . Follow this to know more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: The console.log does not display anything, nor does `alert(res)`, the method is called however, since `getTestFaculties = (faculty_name)=> {
  alert("Incoming="+faculty_name)` does show the incoming faculty name with value `exampleFaculty`.It appears `.then(res => {
    /** Console here to get an actual response from server */
    console.log("res ="+res);` is not executed (even with catch disabled).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205083/discussion-between-a-t-and-alok-mali).